# APP instance not destroyed- Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-ondestroy

Video recording App doesn't get destroyed properly. When i press Back button, the Camera App is onPause(). On starting a new instance of APP the video recording fails. If i manually kill previous instance and re-run APP it works perfect. According to my assumption, all life cycle to kill and release camera are implemented. But the integration or Calls are perhaps creating problem. Need help to sort it out, please.

**CameraPreview Class**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private MyDrawing md;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        // create the surface and start camera preview
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }
    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    setCamera(camera);
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        //startFaceDetection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
    refreshCamera(mCamera);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    //method to set a camera instance
    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
    startFaceDetection();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mCamera.release();
}

private Camera.FaceDetectionListener faceDetectionListener = new Camera.FaceDetectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera c) {

        if (faces.length > 0) {

            Log.d("FaceDetection", "face detected X and Y are as: " + faces.length +
                    " Face 1 Location X: " + faces[0].rect.centerX() +
                    "Y: " + faces[0].rect.centerY() +" LIES IN "+(MyDrawing.w-MyDrawing.radius) +"--"+(MyDrawing.w+MyDrawing.radius));

            if(faces[0].rect.centerX()>=0 && faces[0].rect.centerX()<115 )
            {
                Log.d("ALERT = ", "Detection Started" );
                AndroidVideoCaptureExample.capture.setText("Recording/ stopNsave ");
                AndroidVideoCaptureExample.faceDetect();
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("FaceDetection", "circle cordinates are as: " + (MyDrawing.w-MyDrawing.radius) +"cX"+ MyDrawing.radius+"cY");

        }
    }
};

public void startFaceDetection(){
    // Try starting Face Detection
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    // start face detection only *after* preview has started
    if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0){
        // camera supports face detection, so can start it:
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
    }
}
}
```

**Main**

```
  public class AndroidVideoCaptureExample extends Activity {
     private static Camera mCamera;
     private static  int vWidth,vHeight;
     private CameraPreview mPreview;
     public static  MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
     public static Button capture, switchCamera;
     private Context myContext;
     private FrameLayout cameraPreview;
     private boolean cameraFront = false;
     private static int desiredwidth=640, desiredheight=360;
     private MyDrawing md;
     public static boolean vRecording = false; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        myContext = this;
        initialize();
        Log.d("FaceDetection", "face detected BASEER" );
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }
        if (mCamera == null) {
            // if the front facing camera does not exist
            if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mCamera = Camera.open(findFrontFacingCamera());
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);

        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
        cameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);
        capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(captrureListener);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other
        // applications
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        // check if the device has camera
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static boolean  recording = false;
    OnClickListener captrureListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (recording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, vWidth+"BY"+vHeight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                recording = false;
            }

        }
    };


    public static void faceDetect()
    {
        prepareMediaRecorder();
        recording = true;
        mediaRecorder.start();
    }




    private static void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private static boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

        List<Camera.Size> videosizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes();
        Camera.Size videosize = videosizes.get(1);
        Camera.Size optimalVideoSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(videosize, desiredwidth, desiredheight);
        vWidth = optimalVideoSize.width;//mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
        vHeight = optimalVideoSize.height;//mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512* 1000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(optimalVideoSize.width, optimalVideoSize.height);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private static  Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(Camera.Size sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.2;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
         Camera.Size size = sizes;

            Log.d("Camera", "Checking size " + size.width + "w " + size.height
                    + "h");
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) <= ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the
        // requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }

        }
        return optimalSize;
    }


    }
```

**ErrorLog**

> Error/Crash:If App goes to foreground and reopens, As soon as face is detected (video recording starts on this detection)App crashes with following Error.

```
 E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42230c08)
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample, PID: 8350
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample.AndroidVideoCaptureExample.faceDetect(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.java:141)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample.CameraPreview$1.onFaceDetection(CameraPreview.java:105)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1015)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What happens when the app goes into `onPause()` and then you bring it back to the foreground? Does it crash? Do you get an error? It looks like you are only handling setting up the Camera in your `onResume()` which means all of your other objects are still thinking the old Camera is still there, which was actually set to null in `onPause()`. Your objects may be looking for the old Camera instance, which no longer exists.

Comment: During video capturing if i exit App ( probably calls onPause() )  and then reopen the same instance or even a new one App crashes. Why aren't camera resources being released on improper exit by User.

Comment: Drschultz, the onResume() camera is refreshed and passed to onRefrehCamer()  of CameraPreview Activity as well. Thus, camera is refreshed at both places where conrol is likely to return on Resuming a Paused instance. can't figure the problem out.

Comment: I can't see an `onDestroy()` implementation on your activity. Can you add it and perform a full release there and then see if it works? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Override
 public void onDestroy()
 {
  super.onDestroy();
  mCamera.release();
  mediaRecorder.release();
 } Added it in Main. Now App crashes as soon as i close it (Back Button press)

Comment: Kha, on presing HOME during App running and later restarting new OR re-running old instance leads to APP Crash. While pressing Back button during recording leads to App crah as well.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash please...

Comment: drschultz. Can you plz look into stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CameraPreview.surfaceDestroyed()** release the camera, but does not set `mCamera = null;`. When the app is recalled from background, **AndroidVideoCaptureExample.onCreate()** may be skipped, so the **mPreview** object with an old **mCamera** reference will be used. Now if **surfaceChanged()** is executed before **AndroidVideoCaptureExample.onResume()** calls **mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);**, you are screwed.

The easy fix would be to add `mCamera = null;` to **CameraPreview.surfaceDestroyed()**, and check `if (camera == null) { return; }` in the beginning of **CameraPreview.refreshCamera(Camera camera)**.

---

BTW, **CameraPreview.surfaceCreated()** has some broken code:

```
if (mCamera == null) {
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    …
```

You can simply delete all this block, these operations will be performed in **refreshCamera()** called from **surfaceChanged()**.

You can also remove the second parameter from **CameraPreview** constructor.

Comment: Alex, Thanks for such expert opinion. I have changed code as per ur highlighted points. Can you please look into the Logcat error i posted along this Question. Sending App to foreground while its recording and then restarting/reopening is only case crashing APP now.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of those `static` variables and see if that solves your problem.  When your last activity is finished, the Android framework may keep the process and VM alive to reduce the startup overhead the next time you launch the app.  When that happens, all your `static` variables will retain their old values.  (Your `Application` instance may also be retained, so beware of putting any data there, and never count on `Application#onCreate(...)` being called when your app is launched.)

Comment: Kevin, Problem is if i let proper case run (Face detects, video records, saves and press Stop button at end) no error occurs on rerunning  such properly ended instance from foreground. BUT sending App to foreground while its recording and then restarting/reopening it APP crashes. Why it works fine in one case and fails in other